# Symfony2 Controller does not recognize POST request after jquery changed input value

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, post, get

the following input field i have in my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="editShapeStatus" id="editShapeStatus" value="keep" />
```

the user can perform multiple actions which could change the value of the input.

the jquery function to change the value:

```
 $('#editShapeStatus').val("lto");
```

now it gets funny. althought the form has method="POST" as an attribute, the server receives an GET request. BUT only if the value of editShapeStatus was changed by jQuery. An it gets better:

currently the value can be changed to "lto" and "uls". If i use firebug to change the status manually back to "keep", the server receives a normal POST request. If i change the value to any of the other two manually, the server receives a GET request. Even changing the status names that can be passed to the input as the value will not work. This only results in those two newly named status to cause the same error. interestingly enough, manually changing the value to any other string does work properly. even if i change the status names of "lto" and "uls", those two could be used, but not the new names.

So i thought it must have something to do with jQuery. But the only way i am using it to alter the value i listed above.

any suggestions?

Edit:

the form:

```
 <form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ path('save_border') }}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="borderId" id="borderId" value="{{ border.id }}" /> {# here it tells the controller that we have an existing border to edit #}
                <input type="hidden" name="editShapeStatus" id="editShapeStatus" value="keep" />
                <input type="hidden" name="toLink" id="toLink" value="no" />
                <input type="hidden" name="shapeId" id="shapeId" value="{{ border.borderShape.id }}" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="vertices" id="vertices" required /> {# here the vertices need to be stored #}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="countryName" id="countryName" placeholder="Germany" value="{{ border.name }}" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="year" id="year" placeholder=1868 value="{{ border.year }}" required />
                    <input type="hidden" name="adbcValueMeta" id="adbcValueMeta" value="{% if border.year < 0 %}bc{% else %}ad{% endif %}" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="adbcSwitcherMeta">{% if border.year < 0 %}BC{% else %}AD{% endif %}</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Description">{{ border.description }}</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit" id="submitCountryBorderButton">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

function to change the value of #editShapeStatus:

```
$(document).on('click', '#useShapeForEditing', function() {
        $('#editShapeStatus').val("uls");
    });
```

the #userShapeForEditing button gets created dynamically.

Comment: Even if the form has a POST method if you have setup your jQuery AJAX as a GET request the GET will be performed. Show us your jQuery code.

Comment: $('#editShapeStatus').val("lto"); is the only jquery code i use to alter the values. the form gets submitted by a normal <button type="submit">

Comment: Show us some more code, both HTML and jQuery. How do you submit this form?

Comment: i added the form and the jquery code to alter the value of #editShapeStatus

Comment: **HTML as seen by your browser** is usually more helpful to humans and jQuery/JS. ...:) Quite likely you have other factors to could lead to the weird behavior you describe ... the one jQuery line is not the likely culprit.

Comment: thats what i am thinking. i hoped somebody had a similar problem once and knew what to do. what really confuses me is that chaning the value to anything you like via firebug works perfectly. only the values that could theoretically be inserted by jquery do not work. but (hand to god), those values are only mentioned that one time. there is no pre-submit check no nothing. firebug even displays a post request, but the server receives something different.

Comment: If you can extract from your browser the relevant HTML and create a jsfiddle, we can help you figure that out .. or in the process you might stumble on a solution .. :) what do you think? We are here to help where we can.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DWWUR/1/ i made the input in question of type "text" not "hidden" so one can see the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony returned not quite accurate response when it said it could not find the GET Route. There was acutally a call to a method of an entity that did not exist anymore. How Symfony managed to see that as a problem of routing does escape my knowledge, since the controller referenced by the route was indeed called.

The weird behaviour, which i thought was caused by jquery was actually just the result of the controller, who only executed that said non-existent method when the value in editShapeStatus was correct (if - else). thats why it worked with anything else.

Comment: Glad you found a solution :) Is it not the `POST` route it could not find?

Comment: no the route was perfectly alright. just the controller was malfunctioning.

Answer (score 0):

With the jsfiddle you provided, I clicked `link` and the value changed as you'll see below. Then I clicked save and a `POST` was made ... not a `GET`:

```
Remote Address:162.243.204.190:80
Request URL:http://fiddle.jshell.net/border/save/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 NOT FOUND
Request Headersview source
..........
Form Data:
borderId:12
editShapeStatus:uls
toLink:no
shapeId:38
vertices:
countryName:Poland
year:1868
adbcValueMeta:ad
description:blabla
```

And I also confirmed that a `POST` request is made when the value as is: `keep`.

**Therefore jQuery has nothing to do with the changing of the request method from `POST` to `GET`. We must look elsewhere!**

Comment: Thanks for checking. Here is what happens when i send the request in my project and analyse it with firebug: it is a "POST" request going out. i can even see the parameters. everything looks fine. The Symfony Controller returns the following answer: No route found for "GET /user/map/border/save/": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)

Comment: Sounds like you do not have a `POST` route set up in your routes.php but probably have a `GET` route which makes your `POST`s be redirected to `GET`s ... you need a route like: `Route::post('/border/save', array('uses', 'controllername@methodname'))`

Comment: this is my route configuration: map_save_border:
    pattern: /save/
    defaults: { _controller: XXXBundle:Border:saveBorder }
    methods:  [POST]

Comment: Since the issue seems to be related to your `MVC` environment either you could reword your question or as a new question and state clearly that your **POST route is not getting recognized by your environment**. I just started working with `Laravel` and may not be of much help, even though I am quite willing to help.

Comment: thanks for your help. i found the problem... i was looking in the wrong direction it seems. if you just started laravel this problem might help you some day :) i d give you a vote up if i had the reputation :(